# How to use a txt file content as search term in Entrez.esearch?

Tags: python, biopython

What I did to open the file:

```
lines = []

with open('seq.3p.peixes.seq') as f:
  lines = f.readlines()

count = 0
for line in lines:
  count += 1
  print(f' {line}')
```

And then I want to be able to use each of its lines' content as the search term instead of writing one by one.
Example of the file (they are on separate lines):
`MZ051983.1`
`MZ051929.1`
`MZ051921.1`

```
from Bio import Entrez

Entrez.email  = "youremail@gmail.com"
search_term   = "MZ051983.1, MZ051929.1, MZ051921.1"
handle        = Entrez.esearch(db="nucleotide", term="search_term", usehistory="y", idtype="acc")
record        = Entrez.read(handle)
handle.close()
print(record.keys())
record['IdList']
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your examples your are quite close to the solution. Depending of your need, you could write this as a "singleton" but I would go for a more "elaborate" solution by using functions. Also in your first code sample you use a counter but I dont get the point of it so feel free to adapt below code:

```
def get_file_data(file_path): # file_path could be sys.argv|1] for a standalone script
    with open(file_path) as f:
      return f.readlines()
      
def search_term(term):
    Entrez.email  = "youremail@gmail.com" # for optimisation this should be handled outside of the function, probably using constants or POO
    handle        = Entrez.esearch(db="nucleotide", term=f"{term}", usehistory="y", idtype="acc")
    record        = Entrez.read(handle)
    handle.close()
    print(record.keys())
    return record['IdList']
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    records = []
    for i in get_file_data("file_path.seq"):
        records.append(search_term(i))
    # do something with records
```

Comment: I really appreciate the answer @May.D! But i'm a beginner, i've been using python for less than 3 weeks and the technical words u used i dont quite follow.. Could I not use at all this line? >> search_term   = "MZ051983.1, MZ051929.1, MZ051921.1" Bc i wish i didnt have to write them at all, just the headers on the file.. Im sorry if i didnt understand

Comment: I forgot to remove this line when I pasted the code but yes you dont need it anymore, if you give a closer look it's not used in the function.